# Doing an ActionRequest call from JS/jQuery/Ajax in Spring MVC

Tags: java, javascript, spring-mvc, liferay

I'm trying to redirect to a portlet with specific parameters from JavaScript. I take parameters based on which link the user clicks (this part is OK, I get all the data I need), and afterwards construct an URL which I try to get with simple JS window.location..

My Controller:

```
@RenderMapping
public String view(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("some", "stuff");
    return "myPortlet/view";
}

@ActionMapping(params = "action=importantAction")
public void doAction(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response){
    String foo = request.getParameter("one");
    String bar = request.getParameter("two");
    System.out.println("Got " + one + " & " + two);
}
```

My JS:

```
function myFunction(one_val, two_val){
    window.location = "http://www.my.url.com/nameOfMyPortlet?one=" + one_val +
        + "&two=" + two_val + "&action=importantAction";
}
```

This redirects to the correct page, however the action parameter keeps getting ignored and the whole doAction method doesn't get executed.

**How to pass the action parameter to the target portlet from JavaScript?**

I'm using Liferay & Spring MVC..

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to find a way how it works - it's very similar to what @Ankit P wrote:

I have created hidden fields for the parameters and then sent the form which creates the URL:

JSP:

```
<liferay-portlet:actionURL var="link">
    <liferay-portlet:param name="action" value="importantAction"/>
</liferay-portlet:actionURL>
<form action="${link}" method="POST" name="the-form" id="the-form">
    <input type="hidden" value="" name="one" id="one"/>
    <input type="hidden" value="" name="two" id="two"/>
</form>
```

JS:

```
function myFunction(one_val, two_val) {
    document.getElementById("one").value = one_val;
    document.getElementById("two").value = two_val;
    document.getElementById("the-form").submit();
}
```

Controller stays the same. To use `@ActionMapping` you have to use POST method.

Comment: I agree. The @ActionMapping will only be mapped if the request method is "post". I had faced this issue earlier and resolve by setting the request method to "post".

Answer (score 1):

Did you try creating action URL using below way ?

var portletURL = new Liferay.PortletURL('ACTION_PHASE');
            portletURL.setWindowState("maximized");
In portletURL you can set your desired parameter for calling your action.

Below link for reference

http://www.liferay.com/web/eduardo.lundgren/blog/-/blogs/liferay-portleturl-in-javascript